# Can't change @State var

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have SwiftUI view which I want to change after checking user log-pass. I'm trying to change `isAuth` var like you can see below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Auth : View, AuthProtocol {
    @State private var isAuth = false
    
    init() {
        userManager.notifier = self
    }
    
    var body : some View {
        if isAuth {
            WelcomeView()
        } else {
            VStack {
                Divider()
                Text("Please, wait a minute...")
                Divider()
            }
            .frame(width: 450, height: 350)
        }
    }
    
    func passAuth() {
        if userManager.validateUser() {
            self.isAuth.toggle()
            print("isAuth: \(isAuth)")
        }
    }
}
```

And I got output `isAuth: false`.
I call passAuth func from this code

```
class <classname> {
    var notifier : AuthProtocol!

    func fetchUsers() {
        db.collection("users").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    var newUser = UserData()
                    newUser.login = document["login"] as! String
                    newUser.name = document["name"] as! String
                    newUser.password = document["password"] as! String
                    newUser.accessLevel = document["access_level"] as! Int
                    self.usersList.append(newUser)
                }
                self.notifier.passAuth()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why value of isAuth isn't changing...

Comment: You should not try to modify a `@State` property from outside the view in the first place. I think you should read up on ObservableObject and `@Publisher`

Comment: You can accomplish it by putting an `@Binding` to `isAuth` in your class and passing `$isAuth` to its initializer, but from a design perspective that's kind of messy.  It couples your user manager with a `View`.  Joakim's suggestion about `ObservableObject` would be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use MVVM in swiftui. so we need a viewModel. now when the network request resutl will come we can update our view model and the change will be reflected by the View, simple right? i advice you to check out swiftui tutorials.

```
struct Auth : View  {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
   // @Binding var isAuth: Bool // should use binding is isAuth will be passed by a parent view
    var body : some View {
        if viewModel.isAuth {
            Text("WelcomeView()")
        } else {
            VStack {
                Divider()
                Text("Please, wait a minute...")
                Divider()
            }
            .frame(width: 450, height: 350)
        }
    }
     
}
```

---

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isAuth = false

    func fetchUsers() {
        db.collection("users").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    var newUser = UserData()
                    newUser.login = document["login"] as! String
                    newUser.name = document["name"] as! String
                    newUser.password = document["password"] as! String
                    newUser.accessLevel = document["access_level"] as! Int
                    self.usersList.append(newUser)
                }
                //
                if validateUser() {
                self.isAuth = true
                }
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```